# Getting unreadable characters while converting binary data into text

Tags: java, binary, binaryfiles, data-conversion, binary-data

I'm trying to convert the binary code using java but the binary code is getting converted fine except for the below binary codes, In the entire file wherever we have the first two characters as "11*******" in the binary code that doesn't convert into readable character, except such kind of binary codes, rest all binary code is getting converted successfully.

For example the binary code such as "11000000", "11100010" and "11011010",after conversion, the text comes out to be "À","â" and "Ú" respectively.

My code for conversion

```
    String[] singleBinaryArray = binary.toString().split("\\s");
    String finalResult = "";
    for (String string : singleBinaryArray) {
        Character c = (char) Integer.parseInt(string, 2);
        finalResult += c.toString();
    }
```

Comment: What's the problem? What should they convert to?

Comment: Integer.parseInt("11000000", 2) = 192，“À” is 192th character in unicode encoding

Comment: The issue is these binary codes are getting converted into weird characters(À","â" and "Ú). it's not printing the correct valid readable character for example for binary code string "00110000 00100000 01100011 01101111 01110101 01101110 01110100 01110010 01101001 01100101 01110011 00100000" gets converted into "countries" which makes sense  but wherever we have the binary code as "11000000", "11100010" and "11011010" in the binary code string, there it doesn't make sense at all, the string comes out be after conversion as "time  simple  planâ was written as â@E4  &N4  %N5  #E6âtired "

Comment: The idea is to convert into a readable meaningful character so that it makes a complete meaningful string when put together with other characters. what does these "À","â" and "Ú" characters mean?